# What does $\{a_n| n\in \mathbb N\}^-=M$ mean?

Tags: real-analysis, notation

Currently trying to do a problem for homework. It depends, at least in part, on the result of a previous problem we haven't done. The result labels this as a condition for the result to hold, but I don't know what the sign on the end of the set means as I have not encountered it before. It is from exercise 40.16 (p.141) of Pfaffenberger and Johnsonbaugh's Foundations of Mathematical Analysis.

So, what does $\{a_n| n\in \mathbb N\}^-=M$ mean? In the hint section at the back of the book it says to use Theorem 40.2 to prove exercise 40.16, and that theorem deals with limits, so my intuition is that it has something to do with left-hand limits (this seems queer though as theorem 40.2 deals with limits at infinity) but I haven't a good idea really. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I would guess it is poor typesetting for $\overline{\{ a_n \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}}$, the closure of the set $\{a_n \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$. Does that fit in the context?

Comment: Yes, that fits it perfectly actually. Thank you so much.